# Group a list weekly to a new list and sum one of its field?

Tags: java

I have two entities :

```
class Entry {
   long amount;
   long date; //date is stored in millis
   long id;
   //getter and setters
}

class GroupedEntryByWeek {
   long amount;
   long startDate; // start date of week
   long endDate; // end date of week
   long id;
}
```

Now I want to "`List<Entry> entries`" to generate new list "`List<GroupedEntryByWeek> groupedEntries`"

I want to create a function:

```
public List<GroupedEntryByWeek> groupEntries(List<Entry> entries) {
   List<GroupedEntryByWeek> groupedEntries;
   // code for grouping         

   return groupedEntries;
}
```

which will return me a grouped list

```
Ungrouped list :

id        amount       date
1          500         9th june in millies 
2          600         8th june in millies
3          700         1st june in millies
```

Grouped list should be like :

```
    id        amount       startdate   enddate 
    1          700         28May       3June
    2          1100        4june       9june
```

Comment: And your question is? What ave you tried?

Comment: startdate will be the date on which the week starts and enddate is the date when week ends

Answer (score 2):

If I correctly understand the question you need to create the instance of `List<GroupedEntryByWeek>` in your `Entry` class.

Like this:

```
class Entry {
   long amount;
   long date; //date is stored in millis
   long id;

   List<GroupedEntryByWeek> groupedEntries;

   //getter and setters
}
```

Then when you will iterate trough entries list you get grouped entries from each entry:

```
for (Entry entry : entries) {
   List<GroupedEntryByWeek> groupedEntries = entry.getGroupedEntries();
}
```

Comment: no i want to create a funtion public List<GroupedEntryByWeek> groupEntries(List<Entry> entries)  which will return a list of grouped by week

Comment: So than explain your question properly.